# Connect Google colab to a runtime on a Google Compute Engine instance

Tags: python, ssh, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am trying to connect a jupyter notebook on Google colab to a runtime on GCP EC2 instance. I followed this colab doc instructions [Link](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html)

Steps taken:

- Set up a Jupyter server on my local

  ```
  pip install jupyter_http_over_ws && jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws

  jupyter notebook \
   --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
   --port=8888 \
   --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
  ```
- Create and start a EC2 instance on GCP
- SSH into EC2 instance and forward local port using:

  ```
  gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "europe-west2-c" "<ec2-instance-name>" --project "<project-name>" -- -L 8888:localhost:8888
  ```

Error Message from trying to forward the port:

```
bind [127.0.0.1]:8888: Address already in use
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 8888
Could not request local forwarding.
```

I also tried connecting the ec2 instance directly to colab but I was unable to. For the final step, I am suppose to copy the Jupyter url to the colab local runtime. How can I fix this?

Comment: What if you forward to a different port on localhost?

Comment: SSHing into the instance on a different port or the same port after shut downing the jupyter server works. But what i want to do is to forward the traffic from colab to jupyter server to ec2 instance. @IgorRivin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out.

Steps:

- Start instance
- Connect to instance and forward port on remote instance to local machine

  ```
  gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "<zone>" "<ec2-instance-name>" --project "<project-name>" -- -L 8888:localhost:8888
  ```
- Install jupyter notebook and jupyter_http_over_ws if you dont have it install on the
  remote instance already.
- Then enable `jupyter_http_over_ws`:

  ```
  jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws
  ```
- Start Jupyter server on remote instance

  ```
  jupyter notebook \
   --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
   --port=8888 \
   --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
  ```
- Copy server url to colab