# Colab - connectiong to a custom GCE VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-vertex-ai

How can I connect to a user managed notebook instance of Vertex AI on GCP from google colab.

I have tried by providing the following details but it is complaining as instance is not present.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect Google colab to a runtime on a Google Compute Engine instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61900698/connect-google-colab-to-a-runtime-on-a-google-compute-engine-instance)

Comment: @SakshiGatyan this is working for a normal EC2 instance but I need it for vertex ai notebook instaces

Comment: Connecting to a Colab backend requires using the [Colab Marketplace VM image](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/colab-marketplace-image-public/colab). Vertex AI backends are not supported. See [full documentation here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/marketplace.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connecting to a Colab backend requires using the [Colab Marketplace VM image](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/colab-marketplace-image-public/colab).

Vertex AI backends are not supported.

See [full documentation here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/marketplace.html).